# Multi Level xml to unordered list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pulling my hair out trying to create an unordered list from an xml file with no luck so far.I know how to process the xml from jQuery but I am not able to figure out how to make the multi-level unordered list.

Here is what I have achieved so far.

The xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parent>Director
    <Children>Exe Director1</Children>
    <Children>Exe Director2</Children>
    <Parent>Exe Director2
        <Children>Sub Director 1</Children>
        <Children>Sub Director 2</Children>
        <Parent>Sub Director 3
            <Children>Cameraman 1</Children>
            <Children>Cameraman 2</Children>
        </Parent>
    </Parent>    
</Parent>
```

The html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var levels;
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: xmlParser
        });
    });
    function xmlParser(xml)
{
    $(xml).find("Children").each(function()
    { 
        var text = $(this).text();
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ListContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the expected list

```
<ul>
    <li>Exe Director1</li>
    <li>Exe Director2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Sub Director 1</li>
        <li>Sub Director 2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Cameraman 1</li>
            <li>Cameraman 2</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Can you guys please help me out!

Edit:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var levels;
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) { xmlParser($(xml)); }
        });
    });
    function xmlParser(xml) {
        //alert($(xml).contents());  
        var $ul = $("<ul>"); // For each Parent, create an <ul>
        $(xml).contents().each(function (i, el) {
            if (el.nodeType == 3) return true;
            if (el.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "CHILDREN") 
            {
               $("<li>").text($(el).text()).appendTo($ul); // Append <li> Children
            } else 
            {
               $ul.append(xmlParser($(el))); // Recursively append the other Parent
            }
            //$("#ListContainer").append($ul);
        });
        //alert($ul.html());
        $("#ListContainer").append($ul);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ListContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Bergi I understand that I need to iterate over `Children` to create the list.But to do it recursively , do I need to act upon `parents("Parent")` ? My knowledge in jQuery is pretty much limited.Sorry.

Comment: It's not a jQuery problem, but a standard programming problem. You can (and should?) solve it without jQuery, too. Try to iterate the DOM *tree*, instead of all elements (of one type) at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursively construct the unordered list:

```
function xmlParser($xml) {   
    var $ul = $("<ul>"); // For each Parent, create an <ul>
    $xml.contents().each(function (i, el) {
        if (el.nodeType == 3) return true;
        if (el.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "CHILDREN") {
           $("<li>").text($(el).text()).appendTo($ul); // Append <li> Children
        } else {
           $ul.append(xmlParser($(el))); // Recursively append the other Parent
        }
    });
    return $ul;
}
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mLCCK/)**. Think of each group `Parent` and respective `Children` as a separate unit. For example, if your XML looked like the following:

```
<Parent>Director
    <Children>Exe Director1</Children>
    <Children>Exe Director2</Children>
</Parent>
```

The resulting HTML would be:

```
<ul>
    <li>Exe Director1</li>
    <li>Exe Director2</li>
</ul>
```

How would you construct this? It's quite simple: create an `<ul>` element, and for each `Children` append a `<li>` element to it. Now, for the recursive part, when you introduce another `Parent`, you simply create another `<ul>` again is if it were a single unit, and append its result to the *parent* `<ul>`.

Note that the function that I've used above requires a jQuery object to passed as an argument, thus you'd need to change your `success` handler:

```
success: function (xml) {
  xmlParser($(xml));
}
```

Comment: Silva : The $xml.contents() is throwing an error :( Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Document> has no method 'contents'

Comment: @harsha: Pass a jQuery object to the function, that this, use `success: function (xml) { xmlParser($(xml)); }`.

Comment: @Silva : thanks for all the help.But I am not able to get the list in the right format.What is happening is that individual lists are being created instead of a nested one.I am updating the latest code here.Can you please take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

first, change the `success: xmlParser` syntax,

```
success: function(data){
    xmlParser(data)
}
```